# Django: Having 2 cookie sessions but app gets logged out when the admin app gets logged in (viceversa)

Tags: django, session-cookies, django-middleware

I want to have 2 sessions, one for my application (myapp.com) and one for the admin (myapp.com/admin). With this, I can have access to both in different tabs of my web client without logging in every time I want to use one of them. It is very irritating.

I have created a new session middleware to control that.

```
import time
from importlib import import_module

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.base import UpdateError
from django.core.exceptions import SuspiciousOperation
from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.utils.http import http_date


class AdminCookieSessionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        self.get_response = get_response
        engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
        self.SessionStore = engine.SessionStore

    def cookie_name(self, request):
        parts = request.path.split('/')
        if len(parts) > 1 and parts[1].startswith('admin'):
            return settings.ADMIN_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME
        return settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME

    def cookie_path(self, request):
        parts = request.path.split('/')
        if len(parts) > 1 and parts[1].startswith('admin'):
            return settings.ADMIN_SESSION_COOKIE_PATH
        return settings.SESSION_COOKIE_PATH

    def process_request(self, request):
        session_key = request.COOKIES.get(self.cookie_name(request))
        request.session = self.SessionStore(session_key)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """
        If request.session was modified, or if the configuration is to save the
        session every time, save the changes and set a session cookie or delete
        the session cookie if the session has been emptied.
        """
        try:
            accessed = request.session.accessed
            modified = request.session.modified
            empty = request.session.is_empty()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            # First check if we need to delete this cookie.
            # The session should be deleted only if the session is entirely empty
            if settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME in request.COOKIES and empty:
                response.delete_cookie(
                    settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
                    path=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_PATH,
                    domain=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                )
            else:
                if accessed:
                    patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
                if (modified or settings.SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST) and not empty:
                    if request.session.get_expire_at_browser_close():
                        max_age = None
                        expires = None
                    else:
                        max_age = request.session.get_expiry_age()
                        expires_time = time.time() + max_age
                        expires = http_date(expires_time)
                    # Save the session data and refresh the client cookie.
                    # Skip session save for 500 responses, refs #3881.
                    if response.status_code != 500:
                        try:
                            request.session.save()
                        except UpdateError:
                            raise SuspiciousOperation(
                                "The request's session was deleted before the "
                                "request completed. The user may have logged "
                                "out in a concurrent request, for example."
                            )
                        response.set_cookie(
                            self.cookie_name(request),
                            request.session.session_key, max_age=max_age,
                            expires=expires, domain=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                            path=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_PATH,
                            secure=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE or None,
                            httponly=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY or None,
                        )
        return response
```

In my settings file:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME='usersessionid'
ADMIN_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME='adminsessionid'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'core.utils.middleware.AdminCookieSessionMiddleware'
]
```

However, I have still the problem that if logging in one of the apps, i got automatically logged out of the other.

I was tracing the sessionkey and sometimes it is the same for both coockies. is that ok? If not, what should the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I could fix it, therefore I post the answer so I can help somebody trying to do that as well. I copy the code from the django SessionMiddleware and added a cookie_name function. Inside I created the logic that should apply for my needs.
Remember to replace settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME for cookie_name.

```
import time
from importlib import import_module

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.base import UpdateError
from django.core.exceptions import SuspiciousOperation
from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.utils.http import http_date


class MySessionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        self.get_response = get_response
        engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
        self.SessionStore = engine.SessionStore

    def cookie_name(self, request):
        parts = request.path.split('/')
        if settings.DEBUG:
            if len(parts)>1 and parts[1].startswith('admin'):
                return settings.ADMIN_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME    
        else:
            if len(parts)>2 and parts[2].startswith('admin'):
                return settings.ADMIN_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME
        return settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME

    def process_request(self, request):
        session_key = request.COOKIES.get(self.cookie_name(request))
        request.session = self.SessionStore(session_key)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """
        If request.session was modified, or if the configuration is to save the
        session every time, save the changes and set a session cookie or delete
        the session cookie if the session has been emptied.
        """
        try:
            accessed = request.session.accessed
            modified = request.session.modified
            empty = request.session.is_empty()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            # First check if we need to delete this cookie.
            # The session should be deleted only if the session is entirely empty
            cookie_name = self.cookie_name(request)
            if cookie_name in request.COOKIES and empty:
                response.delete_cookie(
                    cookie_name,
                    path=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_PATH,
                    domain=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                )
            else:
                if accessed:
                    patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
                if (modified or settings.SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST) and not empty:
                    if request.session.get_expire_at_browser_close():
                        max_age = None
                        expires = None
                    else:
                        max_age = request.session.get_expiry_age()
                        expires_time = time.time() + max_age
                        expires = http_date(expires_time)
                    # Save the session data and refresh the client cookie.
                    # Skip session save for 500 responses, refs #3881.
                    if response.status_code != 500:
                        try:
                            request.session.save()
                        except UpdateError:
                            raise SuspiciousOperation(
                                "The request's session was deleted before the "
                                "request completed. The user may have logged "
                                "out in a concurrent request, for example."
                            )
                        response.set_cookie(
                            cookie_name,
                            request.session.session_key, max_age=max_age,
                            expires=expires, domain=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                            path=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_PATH,
                            secure=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE or None,
                            httponly=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY or None,
                        )
        return response
```

And this is very important: in settings, in the MIDDELWARE list, you must add it but also remove the SessionMiddleware per default. Insert it in the same position where the normal SessionMiddleware was. The idea is to put it before 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', otherwise, you will get an error.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'core.utils.middleware.MySessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]
```